# Is it possible to change the music in quest mods to something else?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I downloaded a quest mod, The Cathedral on Steam for Oldrim, and it's pretty good but the music isn't. I feel it would benefit much more from an ambient soundtrack. I was wondering if it's possible to add my own music to this particular mod instead of using its own.

Important: the music for the main game must be unchanged and should play as normal when outside of the mod area. Thanks for any ideas :)

Comment: I would imagine you'd need to delve into the CK to see what music files are packed with the mod.

Comment: Thanks for the response - this mod is short and I finished it already. I turned the music off and it was much better :)